# is an out parameter that is never used in the function a dangling/invalid pointer?

Tags: c++

New to C++ and still trying to understand invalid /dangling pointers. For example if I had something like this would that make total an invalid pointer.

```
bool ValidCars(int number, int* total) {
return false;
}
```

Comment: How so?????????

Comment: nope, this code does nothing with total, if it was valid, its still valid, if it was invalid, its still invalid

Comment: note that c++ does not have the concept of 'out' parameters, versus c# that does for example.

Comment: `bool ValidCars(int number, int* total) { delete total; return false; }` now you might have a dangling pointer. The object pointed at by the argument used as the `total` parameter to call `ValidCars` has been snuffed out and the caller may not be aware.

Comment: If the caller's `total` pointer argument that was passed in was, itself, from pointer that had been `delete`'d and not reassigned (such as to `nullptr`), then passing it in as an argument to ValidCars would be **undefined behavior**.  So don't do that.

Comment: The only way to invalidate a pointer is to invalidate the pointer. The function does nothing so, no. Also, a lot of the issues people have with pointers goes away if you use smart pointers. Use smart pointers.

Comment: No.   A dangling pointer is a pointer to a non-existent object.   An unused argument of a function is completely different.     If the caller of your function passed a dangling pointer there is no effect if your function doesn't use that pointer.   If the caller passes a dangling pointer AND your function dereferences that pointer (i.e. uses the object it points at) then the behaviour is undefined.  If the caller passes a valid (non-dangling) pointer and your function doesn't use it, that does not cause the pointer to dangle.

Comment: `return &number` would have been bad, with a return type of `int*` for `ValidCars()`

Comment: @Eljay "_then passing it in as an argument to ValidCars would be undefined behavior_": Whether or not passing an invalid pointer value to a function other than a deallocation function is allowed is implementation-defined, not generally undefined, and I assume that most platforms have no problem with that.

Comment: @user17732522 • That is true of all undefined behavior.

Comment: @Eljay I am talking about the _undefined behavior_ / _implementation-defined behavior_ terminology of the standard, in which they don't have the same meaning. Specifically https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#stc.general-4.sentence-2 and following sentence.

Comment: @user17732522 • after a `delete`, looking at the now-deleted pointer (that has not been re-assigned, say via `= nullptr`) is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer passed to the function will remain unchanged. When parameters are passed they are copied.

Say you pass in "int *X", and it points to memory address 100. In the function you get a pointer, "total", pointing to the same spot, 100. Pointer X remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

No.

#### Dangling Pointer

A “dangling pointer” is one that, like a child’s feet swinging from a chair, doesn’t point to anything in particular.

In other words, its value was not properly obtained from `new` (or `malloc()` or any other appropriate memory allocator), and so the thing it references is almost certainly *not* what it says it is.

`NULL` is not a dangling pointer — it has an explicit value with explicit meaning.

#### Invalid Pointer

An “invalid pointer” is one that does not point to a valid object of the referenced type. Hence, dangling pointers are invalid, as is `NULL`.

In other words, an invalid pointer cannot be dereferenced without incurring *undefined behavior*.

#### Examples

```
int   x = 12;       // not a pointer

int * p = &x;       // valid: p’s value is x’s address, 
                    // so dereferencing p gets you x’s value.

int * n = nullptr;  // invalid: nullptr (or NULL) is explicitly 
                    // the invalid pointer value. Do not dereference.

int * q = 12;       // invalid: this is a dangling pointer — who knows where it points? 
                    // Do not attempt to dereference it, or suffer the consequences.
```

Comment: While the result is the same, I'm not sure we can call an uninitialized or improperly initialized pointer a dangling pointer. I could be off base, but to me a dangling pointer is a pointer that at one time pointed to a valid object, but that object has subsequently been released.

Comment: Hmm, good point. You might be right there.

Comment: The standard technically uses "_invalid pointer value_" for the value of a pointer to memory whose storage duration ended and "_indeterminate value_" if a variable (including a pointer) wasn't initialized. A null pointer value is explicitly neither of these in the standard. See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#compound-3.sentence-8.

Comment: Also `int * q = 12;` is of course forbidden in C++ and with explicit cast it would be implementation-defined whether it is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer becomes dangling or invalid when the lifetime and/or storage duration of the object it points to ends. For example:

```
int* p; // p has indeterminate value
{
    int i = 0;
    p = &i; // p points to i
    ValidCars(0, p); // This function doesn't end the lifetime of i
                     // and so p is still pointing to i and non-dangling.
} // Here the lifetime and storage duration of i ends
  // and p becomes dangling and invalid pointer.

ValidCars(0, p); // Whether passing an invalid pointer to the function is allowed
                 // is implementation-defined, but in any case
                 // the function may not dereference the pointer.
                 // Afterwards p is still invalid.

int j = *p; // undefined behavior because p is dangling pointer
```

Just passing a pointer value to a function doesn't change whether or not it is dangling. If it wasn't dangling before, then it won't be dangling after the call, assuming that the called function doesn't end the lifetime of the pointed-to object, e.g. by calling `delete` on the pointer.